# Отладка React тестов

Tags: javascript, react-native

Не получается  настроить отладку тестов в React.
Видела много советов в которых показывается настойка jest в package.json
По умолчанию при создании React в package.json  секция скриптов такая

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

но не могу найти где находится конфиг для jest.
Когда я пробую добавить секцию jest в package.json то запуск теста вообще падает.

Answer (score 2):

Для отладки тестов в браузере необходимо:

1)добавить в секцию скрипт такой код

```
    "test:debug": "react-scripts --inspect-brk test --runInBand --no-cache",
```

2) Запустить этот скрипт ( я использую visual studio code)

3) набрать в Chrome chrome://inspect/#devices

4) нажать Open dedicated DevTools for Node

Вы попадаете в отладку.

Answer (score 0):

У меня работает такой вариант:

```
"scripts": {
    ...,
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "test-coverage": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --verbose --coverage"
}
```

плюс наравне со scripts настройки для jest

```
"jest": {
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ]
}
```

*enzyme-to-json надо установить